# preparation data set for basket analysis in R

Tags: r, analysis, market-basket-analysis

I am currently working with a food hall data set and would like to analysis the baskets. However, I have the following problem:

Here is an extract from my data:

```
basket_id   item_name         item_id
2345        coke 0.5          98
2345        salad 300g        103
7876        water             88
7876        diet coke         95
7876        CANCEL diet coke  95
7876        sushi             143
3498        coffee            23
```

To be able to actually analysis the purchases made by the consumers I need to delete all the cancellations from the data set. Unfortunately, I can't just delete the items containing "CANCEL" because that would distort my results, since I need to delete the canceled plus the item that was canceled. For example the basket no. 7876 contains water, diet coke, CANCEL diet coke and sushi. But the consumer only bought the water and the sushi in the end. What I need is a function that recognizes the cancelation and the item that was canceled and deletes it so that I get a data set that looks like this:

```
basket_id   item_name   item_id
2345    coke 0.5        98
2345    salad 300g      103
7876    water           88
7876    sushi           143
3498    coffee          23
```

So that the actual basket 7876 only contains only the item the consumer purchased in the end. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Lets call your data set `data`. Then

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(
basket_id=c(2345, 
            2345, 
            7876, 
            7876, 
            7876, 
            7876, 
            3498 ),   item_name=c("coke 0.5"        ,
                                  "salad 300g"      ,
                                  "water"           ,
                                  "diet coke"       ,
                                  "CANCEL diet coke",
                                  "sushi"           ,
                                  "coffee"              ),         item_id=c(98,
                                                                             103,
                                                                             88,
                                                                             95,
                                                                             95,
                                                                             143,
                                                                             23)







)

dt <- as.data.table(data)
temp.basket <- dt[item_name%like%"^CANCEL",.(basket_id)]
temp.item <- dt[item_name%like%"^CANCEL",.(item_id)]
dt2 <- dt[!(basket_id%in%temp.basket &item_id%in%temp.item)]
```

The symbol `^` ensures that the `item_name` **starts** with the word `CANCEL`

Comment: With `grepl("CANCEL", dt$item_name)` you will get a logical vector indicating the rows where you have the `CANCEL` word. The problem is to delete the ones that are the begining of the canceled rows. This problem I think it is still there in your proposal.

Comment: @R18 the `!` (not) indicator should take care of it, i think

Comment: What I mean is that I think he wants to delete as well the fourth row in the initial matrix, and I think it only deletes the rows which `CANCEL` in the `item_name` column.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately is it not working a 100%. It selects the right baskets and items for temp.basket and temp.item, however, when I run the last line for dt2 there is no difference between dt and dt2...

Comment: and would it sill work if I have the same item more the once in a basket but only one of them got canceled?! Say the basket 7876 would contain water, sushi, diet coke, diet coke and CANCEL diet coke and the result I need is water, sushi, diet coke...?!

Comment: @K.J.F.T. My guess is that it will not work in that case. As for your first comment maybe if you try `dt2 <- dt[!(basket_id%in%temp.basket &item_id%in%temp.item),]` (i added a comma). It would be useful if you could give a reproducible dataset so that I can try a different way

Comment: @quant Please find a subset of my data set here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxhhTN8ukn05V3V1V1NfRzFpRFU
I hope it is not a hassle that the item names are in German?! And the German equivalent to CANCEL is STORNO!